# Visual SourceSafe is asking me to check-in some files, but checking in others automatically

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am using the command-line to merge one project into another. e.g.

`ss merge $/XXXXXXXX -GF -R`

I am expecting to get outputs like this, these are fine:

```
A.cpp has been merged with no conflicts.
Check in now?(Y/N)n

An automatic merge has occurred and there are conflicts.
Edit C:\XXXXXXXX\B.cpp to resolve them.
```

But what about:

```
C.cpp
Comment for C.cpp:
```

I am prompted for a comment and then VSS is automatically checking in the files for me. I didn't realise what was happening until I had checked in a few files... why is it doing this on these files rather than asking me first like it does on the other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my further tests, I *think* that the check-in was done automatically when the merge would be identical to the source file, i.e. the destination is identical to an earlier copy of the source.

Answer (score 1):

on merge, there are three scenarios comparing the source file to the target: the same, different but can be auto merged, and different with conflicts. c.cpp is possibly the first scenario.

Comment: No there are definitely changes... unchanged files get skipped automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with visual source safe merge is that merge is done on the server. That is  if visual source safe succeeds on merging file, it automatically check in that files on the server. On the other hand subversion and other source control systems merge files on your local workspace instead of remote server.

See following microsoft articles about [Visual Source Safe Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8hk7e2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [How to: Merge File Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181073%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

At step 10.
"Check the database to ensure that the branched file versions have been properly merged."

I automatically check-in to database with default options as it is evident from help document.

Comment: That's not true... in my situation most files are merged successfully but I am prompted to checkin. Only a few files are checked in automatically, the rest end up checked out to my working dir.

Comment: @John Added 2 links for this behavior.